# DataGridView Not Bind IEnumerable<TResult> but does List<TResult>

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, lambda

I've written this code:

```
public List<TResult> SelectAll<TResult>(Func<Regions, TResult> selector) where TResult : class
{
    using (RepositoryDataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        return RepositoryDataContext.Regions.Select<Regions, TResult>(selector).ToList<TResult>();
    }
}
```

and call it from the Form this way:

```
dgvFindFirst.DataSource = clsr.SelectAll<SelectAllRegion>(MY SELECT LAMBDA EXP);
```

but when write a method like this :

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> SelectAll<TResult>(Func<Regions, TResult> selector) where TResult : class
{
    using (RepositoryDataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        return RepositoryDataContext.Regions.Select<Regions, TResult>(selector).AsEnumerable<TResult>();
    }
}
```

DataGridView  Not Bound any Nothing returns.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataGridView` `DataSource` property can be any object that implements one of these interfaces: `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList` or `IBindingListView`, which `List<T>` does, but `IEnumberable<T>` doesn't. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx